# How do I get my horizontal JavaScript program to stop "flashing" vertically upon loading

Tags: javascript

My website is wordswithfriends.net

I downloaded a free news ticker JavaScript program.  It works perfectly except upon loading, especially on slow connections, all of the news ticker items will display vertically in plain HTML for a brief second.  The desired behavior would be to show a blank news ticker until the items are ready to scroll.  The source code is here

http://www.wordswithfriends.net/mytourney/widgets/min.js
http://www.wordswithfriends.net/mytourney/widgets/scroller.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding this to your CSS:

```
#ticker01 {
    display:none;
}
```

And one more line in the script tag above the `ul`:

```
$(function(){
    $("ul#ticker01").show();
    $("ul#ticker01").liScroll();
});
```

Comment: @deltanovember when I load the page now, where I once saw the full `ul`, then the scroller, I now see nothing, then the scroller. Is this now what you wanted?

Comment: You're correct it was a caching issue.  As a side note show() needs to be called before liScroll otherwise it seems to mess with the formatting

Comment: This pisses me off! This answer rips mine, and has no explanation as to why it works, but takes all the credit. More fool you. How can the community learn without an explanation as to how  solution works?

Comment: @JonathonDavidOates: I must be an amazingly fast typist to have stolen your answer within one minute of you posting it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, due to the sparse information provided in your question, and from the source code of the scroller.js script that the div that contains the news items to be scrolled has the class tickercontainer.

I can only assume that the new items inside the div with the class tickercontainer are loaded with everything else on the page, only after this div is loaded (when the DOM is ready) does the scroller.js script style the div and it's contents and start the ticker.

Comment: What does this add, given the accepted answer and its comments?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a class to all the news items and apply a 'display:none' style to that class. You may need to initialize the first element on the document ready event. This should get rid of the initial flash of all the news items.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, due to the sparse information provided in your question, and from the source code of the `scroller.js` script that the `div` that contains the news items to be scrolled has the `class` `tickercontainer`.

I can only assume that the new items inside the `div` with the `class` `tickercontainer` are loaded with everything else on the page, only after this `div` is loaded (when the DOM is ready) does the `scroller.js` script style the `div` and it's contents and start the ticker.

I would suggest you initially set the `visibility` or `display` styles of `tickercontainer` to `hidden` or `none` either in the `style` tag within the `head` tag of your HTML, or in an external CSS file and once the `scroller.js` script has initialised use jQuery to set the `visibility` or `display` styles to `visible` or `block`.

If this is not what you are looking for then please expand on your question and I'll try my best to answer.

Comment: You accepted an answer that is exactly what I have said, but with no explanation as to how the solution works. The answer you accepted is the code that represents my answer. How can the community lean without understanding why a solution works?